# Woocommerce - Display product category of product in Orders page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to show the product category of product in admin Orders page when a customer make a purchase.Appreciate if any one can help. :)
screen shot attached where in need to display product category of product in Orders page. Thanks
[image: admin Order page]

Comment: Please add some source code related to the the problem you're having. What have you done? What is the structure of your code? All these things must be stated clearly in the question. Read this: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The answer seems to be at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73748/get-the-category-from-an-id-of-a-product

Comment: Also post images directly in the question, there's no need to link to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use [`get_the_term_list()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list) and add it to the appropriate hook. You can always find an appropriate hook by searching through the WooCommerce code for some CSS/HTML markup. In this case the `<td class="name">` tag had a `data-sort-value` data attribute. You can usually assume that those aren't going to appear everywhere and aren't dynamically generated, so you can use a decent text editor to search the whole WooCommerce folder. That revealed a `woocommerce_before_order_itemmeta` hook.

Add this to your theme's functions.php or preferably a site-specific plugin.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_itemmeta', 'so_before_order_itemmeta', 10, 3 );
function so_before_order_itemmeta( $item_id, $item, $_product ){
    echo get_the_term_list( $_product->id, 'product_cat', __( 'Categories:', 'textdomain' ), ',', '' ); 
}
```